# Unknown OS 'msys_nt-6.1'. using Mingw on win7 64bit

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw, configure

I try to compile FFmpeg from source using MSYS2  and MIngW I'm using win7 64 bit .
using .

```
$ ./configure --enable-shared
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unknown OS 'msys_nt-6.1'.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

looking in to config.log 
i see ( the end of the log ):

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -c -o /tmp/ffconf.fnJeLuIu.o /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
check_code cc  int test[2*(sizeof(void *) > 4) - 1]
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
    1   int main(void) { int test[2*(sizeof(void *) > 4) - 1]; return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -std=c99 -c -o /tmp/ffconf.fnJeLuIu.o /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
G:/msys64/tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c: In function 'main':
G:/msys64/tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c:1:22: error: size of array 'test' is negative
 int main(void) { int test[2*(sizeof(void *) > 4) - 1]; return 0; }
                      ^
check_cpp_condition stddef.h defined(__x86_64__)
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
    1   #include <stddef.h>
    2   #if !(defined(__x86_64__))
    3   #error "unsatisfied condition: defined(__x86_64__)"
    4   #endif
END /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -std=c99 -E -o /tmp/ffconf.fnJeLuIu.o /tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c
G:/msys64/tmp/ffconf.e8DJYGJM.c:3:2: error: #error "unsatisfied condition: defined(__x86_64__)"
 #error "unsatisfied condition: defined(__x86_64__)"
  ^
Unknown OS 'msys_nt-6.1'.
```

what did i miss ? what did i do wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: work around for now: use msys or cygwin cross compile :|

Answer (score 0):

You should compile it with visual studio, and you'll have to install msys2 and yasm..
Add the following options to the ./configure :

--toolchain=msvc \
    --arch=x86 \
    --enable-yasm \
    --enable-asm\
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static

Check this website, he gives somes explanation:

https://pracucci.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-visual-studio-compiler.html

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't missing anything ffmpeg should build fine with `./configure --enable-shared --target-os=mingw32 --arch=x86_64`.

See here how ffmpeg is built by MSYS2: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-ffmpeg/PKGBUILD#L61